# Template does not exist, django paths

Tags: python, django, rest, server, path

Trying to run my server, but it doesn't seem to be cooperating.

This is the text displayed when I tried running it:

```
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/rest_framework/api.html 
(Source does not exist)
```

I have `'rest_framework'` in my settings, `'INSTALLED APPS'`, I'm not sure what's going on

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your Html files in Templates directory of your project or change your templates directory (from settings.py) to the directory you want

Comment: I don't think I have any html files yet, but I think I want templates should be in settings. I'm not too sure, i'm pretty new to all this.